# Как правильно перенести словарь json в таблицу на postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql

Всем привет.
Изучаю postgres и python.
Собственно вопрос вот в чем:
Есть словарь:

```
    "Вопрос1": [
        "Ответ1",
        "Ответ2"
    ],
    "Вопрос2": [
        "Ответ1",
        "Ответ2"
    ]
```

Никак не могу сообразить, как правильно перенести этот словарь в таблицу postgres, чтобы потом ответы рандомно выбирать по данной команде `select phrase from table where question = 'Вопрос1' order by random() limit 1`
Я понимаю, что phrase это столбец должен быть, выбираем из table, а дальше тупняк страшный...

Comment: а вам не подойдёт обычный random.choice(list(d.keys())) ?

Comment: @Интик, как выбирать из словаря я знаю, но мне нужно понять как составить таблицу на основе этого словаря, чтобы потом из таблицы рандомно выбирать ответы по вопросу

Comment: вы можете хранить весь словарь как `json` и какждый раз обращаясь к ключу(вопросу) выбирать рандомное значение из массива. Либо хранить поле с 'Вопросами' и поле с  массивами `[]varchar`  ответов. Получили строку по условию `where question = 'Вопрос1'` а дальше выбираете рандомное значение из массива.